# Split multiple mkv files from ubuntu terminal using mkvmerge

Tags: command-line, bash, mkv

I have many .mkv files

```
nightmare1.mkv
nightmare2.mkv
nightmare3.mkv
...
```

I use mkvmerge from terminal of Ubuntu to split a *single* file with this command

```
mkvmerge --split 1G --compression 0:none --compression 1:none --clusters-in-meta-seek -o "nightmare1.mkv" "nightmare1.mkv"
```

First nightmare is output, second is input

I get this files

```
nightmare1-001.mkv
nightmare1-002.mkv
...
```

I try to understand how can I split **all** .mkv files in 1gb pieces because I want to get

```
nightmare1-001.mkv
nightmare1-002.mkv
 ...

nightmare2-001.mkv
nightmare2-002.mkv
 ...

nightmare3-001.mkv
nightmare3-002.mkv
 ...
```

All nightmare movies are in the same folder. 
How should I rewrite the command? The problem is that I have the single mkv file as input and I write as output to a file but I want to set the folder path as the input where the mkv files are located and write inside the folder all the new splitted mkv files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Bash `for` loop to solve this task:

```bash
for file in ./source/*mkv; \
do \
    echo mkvmerge --split 1G --compression 0:none --compression 1:none \
    --clusters-in-meta-seek -o "./split/$(basename "$file")" "$file"; \
done
```

- Copy and paste all lines in the terminal and execute them as single command.
- Once you are satisfied from the dry run output of the loop, **remove the `echo` command** to do the actual operations.

In the above example `./source/` is a relative path to the directory where the original files are stored. Respectively `./split/` is the destination path and it must be preliminary crated.

For each iteration the value of the variable `$file` will look like `./source/nightmare-i.mkv`. The command substitution `$(basename "$file")` will return only the filename without the path - i.e. `nightmare-i.mkv`, so the value of the output option will look like `./split/nightmare-i.mkv`.

Comment: Maybe I wrong something about folder creation but I don't understand what, I get these errors: ` `Error: The file '-001./split/' could not be opened for writing: open file error.` and 
`basename: extra operand 'S04E09'` - I made a short video to show you what I've done, look [HERE](https://mega.nz/file/15Q0UYba#8oNM-6PPk65xuxqJbxhzXeBSmhjtwD4pp_6S89CzGjg) please

Comment: Hi, @JackRock, could you post [somewhere](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/) the output of the loop while there is the `echo` command in the front of the other. I've already tested it before post it, and right now I can't realize what is the problem. This is a Bash syntax, are you sure using Bash? If `echo $SHELL` doesn't report `/usr/bin/bash`, then type `bash` and press enter - this this will fork new Bash shell, and try to run the loop again. If this is the problem, I would rewrite the answer.

Comment: Yes, I sure to use Bash, I show you 3 outputs [HERE](https://pastebin.com/raw/XynR1Lcv) - pastebin

Comment: Hi, @JackRock, probably there is [missing quotation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480968/201297). Try to change the relevant entry to: `$(basename "$file")`. I've updated this into the answer.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!